# Finding list of positions in multidimensional structure (array)

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, indexing, position

Suppose I have a simple multidimensional structure, like this one:

```
somestr<-array(sample.int(2, 120, replace=TRUE), dim=c(4,5,6))
```

I'm looking for all positions in the structure (in this case, an array) where the value is equal to, say for my example, 2. Note that the structure might just as well hold characters or logicals. For now, it will do to just find all values equal to a given, but it would be nice to extend the idea to any logical-valued function that can be applied to each item in the structure (That would allow e.g. `is.na`to be used).

What I would like to get, is an (`integer`) matrix with as many columns as `somestr` has dimensions (in this case 3), and as many rows (depends on the sample.int call above) as there are values equal to the given value (2). The values in this new matrix are the 'coordinates' within `somestr` where the values are equal to 2.

I apologize for mixing my example with the explanation, but I was hoping it would be clearer that way. For the record: I'm able to produce this myself (may even answer my own question), but I was hoping for a standardized solution (read: a readymade function in some package), or learn new tricks along the way.

So, in short, can you write a function

```
posOf<-function(somestr, valueToCompareTo)
```

that returns a matrix of the positions in `somestr` equal to `valueToCompareTo`, and if `valueToCompareTo` is a function, the positions in `somestr` for which applying this function returns `TRUE`.

Comment: `somestr` has 3 dimensions; how does that tally with "What I would like to get, is an (integer) matrix with as many columns as somestr has columns, and as many rows as there are values equal to the given value (2). The values in this new matrix are the coordinates within somestr where the values are equal to 2."???

Comment: @Gavin: I don't see how it doesn't. Still, I have edited somewhat in hopes of clarifying.

Comment: `somestr` doesn't have three columns, each slice of the array has five columns, at least from your example (`dim = c(4,5,6)`)! Do you mean three *dimensions*? That is what confused me. My initial guess was to use `which(...., arr.ind = TRUE)` or possibly `arrayInd(..., .dim = 1:3)` directly, but that didn't seem to fit with the description.

Comment: Edited. Sorry, must be awfully Friday.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the `which` function can do that:

```
which(somestr==2, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

(if I understood everything correctly)

```
R> set.seed(123)
R> somestr <- array(sample.int(2, 120, replace=TRUE), dim=c(4,5,6))
R> somestr
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    2    2    1
[2,]    2    1    1    2    1
[3,]    1    2    2    1    1
[4,]    2    2    1    2    2

...

, , 6

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    1    1    1    2
[2,]    1    2    1    2    2
[3,]    1    2    2    2    2
[4,]    2    2    1    1    1

R> which(somestr==2, arr.ind=TRUE)
      dim1 dim2 dim3
 [1,]    2    1    1
 [2,]    4    1    1
 [3,]    1    2    1
 [4,]    3    2    1
 [5,]    4    2    1
...
[57,]    2    5    6
[58,]    3    5    6
```

Comment: Whew! That is beautiful, and I would never have thought of using which for this, although in hindsight it makes perfect sense. I doubt anybody is going to improve on this, but I'll hold my breath for now.