# Get row and column indices of matches using `which()`

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

Say I have some matrix, for example:

```
m = matrix(rep(c(0, 0, 1), 4), nrow = 4)
m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    1
[2,]    0    1    0
[3,]    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    1
```

If I run `which`, I get list of normal indices:

```
> which(m == 1)
[1]  3  6  9 12
```

I want to get something like matrix indices - each index containing the row and column number:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    1
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    1    3
[4,]    4    3
```

**Is there any simple function to do this?** Moreover, it should somehow contain the row and column names:

```
> rownames(m) = letters[1:4]
> colnames(m) = letters[5:7]
> m
  e f g
a 0 0 1
b 0 1 0
c 1 0 0
d 0 0 1
```

but I don't now how, maybe like

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    1    c    e
[2,]    2    2    b    f
[3,]    1    3    a    g
[4,]    4    3    d    g
```

or, maybe return 2 vectors (for rows and columns), like

```
c b a d
3 2 1 4

e f g g
1 2 3 3
```

Comment: see [one of my older questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7204016/709529)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

For your first question you need to also pass `arr.ind=  TRUE` to `which`:

```
> which(m == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   3   1
[2,]   2   2
[3,]   1   3
[4,]   4   3
```

Comment: cool, thanks! I **was** looking at the `?which` help, but it says: *"arr.ind logical - should array indices be returned when x is an array?"*, which is pretty confusing! Why they speak of array indices when they return matrix indices? (With array, I usualy mean 1D vector)

Comment: "array" is the more general case, including "vectors" with a degenerate singleton dimension, matrices (with 2 dimensions), and 3D, 4D, ... arrays - vectors with no dimension are not 1D in this sense, and remember there are recursive vectors as well (list)

Comment: @TomasT. An array can have 1, 2 or more dimensions.  A matrix is the special case of a 2-dimensional array.  See `?matrix` and `?array`.

Comment: I can't believe I never knew about `arr.ind`! I've always used some horrible inefficient hack relying on calls to `row()` and `col()` for this.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot mix numeric and alpha in a matrix, but you can in a data.frame:

```
> indices <- data.frame(ind= which(m == 1, arr.ind=TRUE))
> indices$rnm <- rownames(m)[indices$ind.row]
> indices$cnm <- colnames(m)[indices$ind.col]
> indices
  ind.row ind.col rnm cnm
c       3       1   c   e
b       2       2   b   f
a       1       3   a   g
d       4       3   d   g
```