# Getting dimension values from matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, dimensions

Suppose this is the matrix I'm working with:

[image: Manhattan distances between coordinates]

What is the R code I need to use to get the dimention coordinates of a value? Like, if I wanted to get the coordinates of where the value is '0' , it should return (A,A) , (B,B) , (C,C) , etc... I couldn't find an answer anywhere..

Comment: This might already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7507816/9022665

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

A crude way could be:

```
nms <- dimnames(distance)
mat<- which(distance == 0, TRUE)
cbind(nms[[1]][mat[,1]], nms[[2]][mat[,2]])
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "A" 
[2,] "B"  "B" 
[3,] "C"  "C" 
[4,] "D"  "D" 
[5,] "E"  "E" 
[6,] "F"  "F" 
[7,] "G"  "G"
```

Or even

```
do.call(outer, c(dimnames(distance), paste))[which(distance == 0, TRUE)]
[1] "A A" "B B" "C C" "D D" "E E" "F F" "G G"
```

---

```
distance <- structure(c(0, 5, 6, 9, 10, 8, 8, 5, 0, 1, 10, 11, 7, 9, 6, 1, 
0, 9, 10, 6, 8, 9, 10, 9, 0, 3, 7, 7, 10, 11, 10, 3, 0, 4, 4, 
8, 7, 6, 7, 4, 0, 2, 8, 9, 8, 7, 4, 2, 0), .Dim = c(7L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), c("A", "B", "C", "D", 
    "E", "F", "G")))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `mapply` + `dinames` + `which` like below (thank @Onyambu's data)

```
mapply(
    `[`,
    dimnames(distance),
    data.frame(which(distance == 0, arr.ind = TRUE))
)
```

which gives

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "A" 
[2,] "B"  "B"
[3,] "C"  "C"
[4,] "D"  "D"
[5,] "E"  "E"
[6,] "F"  "F"
[7,] "G"  "G"
```