# Indexing position of 1s in matrix using R apply

Tags: r, loops, matrix, apply

Given a 0/1 matrix, I am trying to generate a list of the index positions of the 1s in each row. I can do this using a `for` loop:

```
B <- matrix(sample(c(0,1),100,replace=T),nrow=10,ncol=10)
ones <- list()
for (row in 1:nrow(B)) {ones[[row]] <- (which(B[row,]==1))}
```

The resulting object `ones` is what I want. I assume using `apply()` will be slightly faster, but I'm having trouble translating the loop into apply. This doesn't yield the same result:

```
alt <- apply(B, 1, function(x) which(B[x,]==1))
```

I'd appreciate any advice on how to correct `apply` so it yields the same result as the loop approach. Thanks!

UPDATE -

I accepted @TarJae’s answer because it works, only requires one line, and is fast. @Ronak’s approach also works, but is slower than either of the other options. Here’s a comparison of the three methods:

```
library(rbenchmark)
B <- matrix(sample(c(0,1),1000000,replace=T),nrow=1000,ncol=1000)
benchmark(
  "loop" = {
    ones_loop <- list()
    for (row in 1:nrow(B)) {ones_loop[[row]] <- (which(B[row,]==1))}
  },
  "apply" = {
    ones_apply <- apply(B==1,1, which)
  },
  "split" = {
    ones_split <- which(B == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
    ones_split <- split(ones_split[, 2], ones_split[, 1])
  },
  replications = 500
)
```

```
   test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
2 apply          500  17.211    1.000    15.068    2.111          0         0
1  loop          500  19.466    1.131    16.778    2.349          0         0
3 split          500  40.291    2.341    33.757    6.150          0         0
```

Comment: Check the `arr.ind` argument of `which`; `which(B == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)`; [`which()` function for matrix indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507765/which-function-for-matrix-indices)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `apply` this was way: Gives the same result as the loop:

```
apply(B==1,1, which)
```

```
> apply(B==1,1, which)
[[1]]
[1]  4  6  7  8 10

[[2]]
[1]  1  4  5 10

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 7 9

[[4]]
[1] 2 3 4 5 9

[[5]]
[1]  2  4  8 10

[[6]]
[1] 4 5 7 8

[[7]]
[1]  1  2  5  8  9 10

[[8]]
[1]  1  3  4  7  8  9 10

[[9]]
[1]  1  2  4  5  6  7 10

[[10]]
[1]  1  3  4  6  7 10
```

Comment: Your soluiton is the fastest.  I thought `asplit` would be fast, but still it lags behind you

Comment: Yeah!!. Perfect!!

Answer (score 1):

`which(matrix, arr.ind = TRUE)` as suggested by @Henrik provides you all the necessary information needed. If you need to have a list output as the `for` loop you can use `split`.

```
set.seed(123)
B <- matrix(sample(c(0,1),100,replace=T),nrow=10,ncol=10)
mat <- which(B == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
split(mat[, 2], mat[, 1])

#`1`
#[1]  2  6  8  9 10

#$`2`
#[1]  2  3  4  5  7  9 10

#$`3`
#[1] 2 5 7

#$`4`
#[1]  1  4  9 10

#$`5`
#[1]  2  4  9 10

#$`6`
#[1] 1 6 7 8 9

#$`7`
#[1] 1 2 3 6 8

#$`8`
#[1]  1  3  5 10

#$`9`
#[1] 6 8 9

#$`10`
#[1] 3 4 8
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `asplit`

```
lapply(asplit(B == 1, 1), which)
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1]  1 10

[[2]]
[1]  3  8  9 10

[[3]]
[1] 1 3 6 7 8 9

[[4]]
[1] 2 5 6 7 9

[[5]]
[1]  1  2  4  5  7 10

[[6]]
[1]  2  8 10

[[7]]
[1] 1 2 6 7 8

[[8]]
[1] 3 7 9

[[9]]
[1]  1  2  4  5  6  7  9 10

[[10]]
[1] 1 4 6 7
```