# Pivoting dataframe cols to rows based on logical condition on values

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe in R and it has ( for example) say 10 rows and 10 columns. The values in dataframe will be either 0 or 1.

Eg

```
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 
...
```

Now I want to output this data to a new file, in this format

```
1 1
1 4
1 9
1 10
2 2
2 4
2 6
2 8
2 10
....
```

Here output format is (row index, col index) where value is 1.

I am doing this in 'for' loops but it is taking too slow to process. Are there any vector/matrix operations or other packages which can do it faster?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `which(dat==1, arr.ind=TRUE)` should do it. Essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507765/which-function-for-matrix-indices or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204016/finding-list-of-positions-in-multidimensional-structure-array unless there is something more you need.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks. It worked, just needed to do an ordering after the result of which() to do row wise ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` functions:

```
## For the following matrix
df <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 25, replace = TRUE), 5, 5)
df
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    1    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    1    0    1    1
# [3,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    1    1    1
# [5,]    1    0    0    1    1

## The positions of the "1" in the columns
col <- apply(df, 1, function(X) which(X == 1))
## The number of "1" per rows
rows1 <- lapply(col, length)
rows2 <- lapply(as.list(1:length(rows1)), function(X, rows1) rep(X, rows1[[X]]), rows1)

## Combining both
cbind(unlist(rows2), unlist(col))

#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
# [2,]    2    2
# [3,]    2    4
# [4,]    2    5
# [5,]    4    3
# [6,]    4    4
# [7,]    4    5
# [8,]    5    1
# [9,]    5    4
#[10,]    5    5
```

Comment: This'll work, but `which` already has an `arr.ind=` argument which does all this heavy lifting.